# React Native component infinitly rerendering after redux store data updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a react-native-pdf component that updates the redux store(state) data on `onPageChanged`. Its parent component is using mapStateToProps.
As soon as I change the page, state-changing reducer is called. However, the component starts to rerender in an infinite loop after the state is updated.

I am not sure why this is happening infinitely instead of only once.
I tried console logging at various points. The store is being updated only once (as expected).
but after that, the rerendering infinite loop starts.
If I don't call the `props.addMetadata()` reducer, the problem doesn't occur

Following is the code:

```
function PdfReader(props) {
...
    
    const { params } = props.route;
    const { progress = 0, totalPages, type } = props.books[params.index]; //get progress, total pages from books in redux store

...
    function updateMetadata(details){
        
      if(details.type!=type||details.totalPages != totalPages || details.progress != progress){
            console.log('metadata updated') // **this happens only once as expected**
            props.addMetadata(details, params.index)
        }
    }

    function goPrev() { pdf.setPage(page - 1) }
    function goNext() { pdf.setPage(page + 1) }
...

console.log('loaded pdf reader') // **This is being logged infinitly**
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Pdf
                ...
                ref={(pdf) => { this.pdf = pdf; }}
                page={progress}
                source={{uri : state.docUrl}}
                onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath)=>{
                    console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
                }}

                onPageChanged={(page,numberOfPages)=>{
                    console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
                    setPage(page)
                    // update progress in metadata
                    updateMetadata({ totalPages: numberOfPages, type: 'pdf', progress: page }, params.index)
            }} />
             </View>
)}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        settings: state.settings,
        books: state.books
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    actions
)(PdfReader);
```

Here is the part of reducer function that is being called by `props.addMetadata`

```
     case 'add_metadata': {
            console.log('metada reducer called')
            let { data, index } = action.payload;
            let stateCopy = [...state];
            stateCopy[index] = { ...stateCopy[index], ...data };
            return stateCopy;
        }
```

Please help me understand why this might be happening.

Comment: I think you are updating ```props```, try to log your store state when ```action``` is dipatched```

Comment: @KamronJurayev I'm calling the `props.addMetadata(details, params.index)` which updates the props.books object. Tried logging when the action is dispatched. the log is happening only once

Comment: @KamronJurayev on updating the store, another action used in the `useEffect` is being called infinitely and consequently rerendering the component.
This was totally unexpected for me! Thank you very much

Comment: glad to help!!!